# Using the JetBrains AWS Elastic Beanstalk integration plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, plugins, pycharm

I'm using the excellent [JetBrains AWS Elastic Beanstalk integration plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7274?pr=idea) (in PyCharm) but have a few related questions on how to accomplish things and how it integrates with the behavior of AWS's `eb` command line tool:

1. Is there a way to take advantage of EB's association between git branches and EB environments? The plugin doesn't seem to use this mapping and instead uses the environment specified in the run configuration dialog.
2. The URL that the application given as being "available at" is wrong. Is this a known bug? Is it something that I can fix?
3. Is there any way to have multiple run configurations for a given deployment (e.g. with different environment names)? Right now whenever I change the environment in one of my run configurations for a deployment, the other run configurations also switch to that environment.

Comment: Looking more closely, it may be that (1) is the result of the plugin using current EB tools while the feature I had discovered was only supported by older versions ([installed by Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27747455/656912)). I'd appreciate having that confirmed.

Comment: Actually, it looks like (1) continues to be an issue even with the current CLI tools installed and default environments associated with my various branches (using `eb use`).