# Can I use Homebrew to install the latest AWS EB CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, homebrew, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Homebrew [appears to install](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/aws-elasticbeanstalk.rb) an [older version (unsupported)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html) of the [AWS EB tools](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743). Is there a way to get Homebrew to install the current ones?

---

(I'm new to Homebrew.)

Comment: No need, the AWS CLIs are now installed with pip. `sudo pip install awsebcli`.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I have to laugh! It seems like every time I ask about installing software I get pushed towards Homebrew (I'm perfectly happy with `pip`) and now — on literally the second package I want to install — it turns out that `pip` has what I want and Homebrew doesn't! (Sigh!)

Comment: This is not an answer, but consider using "brew install awscli" which is now a much better solution to aws CLI tools: http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: @bsravanin: And uninstall the Brew EB first? How do I do that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You can uninstall any formula with "uninstall". Like "brew uninstall aws-elasticbeanstalk". If you had installed the CLI through pip, you would have to accordingly do "pip uninstall" or "sudo pip uninstall".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You'd install something like Python with Homebrew, but Python has its own package managers (pip and easy_install - entertainingly, you typically install pip with easy_install :-p). Node is similar - you'd install Node with Homebrew, but use NPM to install Node packages. Incidentally, love the username.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I'll take your initial comment as an answer. That seems to work — and leads to [a follow-on question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27748032/656912).

Comment: @bsravanin: Things seem to have progressed, so I'm [wondering if migrating to Homebrew makes more sense now](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41490563/656912) (and if it is simple to do).

Answer (score 5):

Homebrew relies on volunteers to keep the formulas updated.  If you notice an outdated formula, please submit a bug or pull request.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that `brew install awscli` works well on macOS Sierra.